# Ruby, variables and their C# equivalent

Tags: c#, ruby, variables

I'm trying to wrap my head around Ruby variables and thought it might be good to see them in terms of C#

could someone tell me the C# equivalent of Ruby's (for example is @@ == public static variable?):

$ global variable
@ instance variable
@@ class variable
[a-z] local variable
[A-Z] constant

any other types of variables I'm missing?

Could someone also explain how @instance variables are used/function?
 
at first I thought it was some global variable in the instance of a class, but then i saw it used with a scope like a local variable in the instance's method.

here's is an example from the 'well grounded rubyist'

```
class C
    def show_var
        @v = "i am an instance variable initialized to a string" 
        puts @v
    end
    @v = "instance variables can appear anywhere..." 
end
C.new.show_var
```

if I wanted 'v' to be the same variable from anywhere in the class instance, what is the Ruby mechanism for doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure the Ruby names for those variables is any exotic. (Besides globals, those don't exist in C#, but aren't an unfamiliar concept.) Maybe elaborate on the uses you're having difficulties with? What do you mean by "I thought it was some global variable in the instance of a class, but then i saw it used with a scope like a local variable in the instance's method"? Or what is "a global variable in the instance"?

Comment: thanks for the reply, so I updated with an example from the 'well grounded rubyist'.  at first i thought that 'new' created @v ("instance variables can..." and then calling 'show_var' replaced it with "i am an instance...". but that isn't the case, they are distinctly two different variables.  i got the right results, but not for the right reasons.

Comment: That's a hilariously confusing example. This demonstrates things better: http://ideone.com/FcBnkn

Comment: Basically, in "class scope" (e.g. outside methods), `@v` points to a "class variable". (Which is more or less a static field, except not really, and it's not even what Ruby calls "class variables", because class variables and instance variables of a class are different things.) Whatever "Well Grounded Rubyist" is, it's doing you a disservice by showing you the above example without explaining the distinction. Or that it's *amazingly* bad practice to use the same name for a class variable and for instance variables of the same class.

Comment: So, yes, they are different variables in that code example, but you shouldn't really worry too much about the fact why this is so yet.

Comment: ok thanks, i think i see the distinctions.  correct me if i'm wrong, but to summarize both class and methods in the class each have their own scope of instance variables.  so that @v in a method is the same across all methods in the instance and @v in the class is applicable to just the class but not accessed by the method nor across any other instances of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does not use [sigils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) for variables.

The "equivalent" C# variable depends *entirely on how the variable/member is defined*. Note that there are differences even between the "equivalent" forms.

However, there are a number of [*naming conventions*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) that are encouraged to be followed. The exact conventions used vary by project and may differ from the names I chose below, which reflect my conventions - do not use "class" or "instance" or "local" in real variable names.

Examples:

```
class MyClass: IMyInterface {

    // "const" makes it constant, not the name
    public const int CONSTANT = 42;

    // static member variable - somewhat like Ruby's @@variable
    private static int classVariable;
    public static int ExposedClassVariable; // but use properties  

    // @variable - unlike Ruby, can be accessed outside "self" scope
    int instanceVariable;
    public int ExposedInstanceVariable;     // but use properties

    void method (int parameter) {
        int localVariable;
    }
}
```

C# does not have "global variables in a shared namespace", but static member variables can be accessed by a *stable path* which means they can be effectively abused as global variables.

Comment: thanks, I understand that C# doesn't require sigils. For the 'int instanceVariable', that's how I originally interpreted ruby's instance variables (@), but the 'well grounded rubyist' had an example (which I updated above) that showed it doesn't exactly operate in the same manner (which is fine they're different languages after all). So i wanted to get at the difference and how to duplicate certain functionality.

Comment: Then you asked a horrid, horrid question and topped it with a horrid title (both *can* and *should* be fixed). The problem with the ruby code is **`@v` *outside* the method is a member variable of the *class instance*** and not an instance variable for the *object instance created from the class*. In both places, `puts self` and note a different result - `@v` variables are always taken to be instance variables of `self`. The correct way to assign an initial value to `@v` (*for the object instance*) would be in the initializer/new method.

Comment: @user1297102 Also, make sure to focus on *one* question per post - I answered the first in my reply, and latter second in my comment. I din't mean to be "so aggressive" in my previous comment - but really work on creating (and improving) questions so that they are clear and focused.

Comment: haha thanks i'll try to be less horrid next time (and keep my questions down to one).  So from your reply/example and the comments above, is this correct?
to summarize, both class and methods in the class each have their own scope of instance variables. so that @v in a method is the same across all methods in the instance and @v in the class is applicable to just the class but not accessed by the method nor across any other instances of the class?

Comment: @user1297102 Yes, *in Ruby* there is a different scope for code in `class` (self is the class, which is itself an object) and code in `def` (self is an object instance of said class) - this is why `puts self` will return different values from the different locations. Ruby *runs the code* in `class` when it's encountered (before any instance of the class can be/are created) whereas in languages like C# the class is *only a definition*.